# Does SQL Server optimize a query when using a string code in the predicate the same as the primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Suppose you have a products table, with the following columns:

```
ProductId [tinyint] | ProductCode [varchar(100)] | ProductName [varchar(8000)] | ...
```

Where ProductCode is unique and not null.

And an orders table:

```
OrderId [int] | LinkProductId [tinyint] | LinkCustomerId [int] | ...
```

If I wanted to periodically sum the number of orders for product "ABC", I might run the following every *x* minutes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Products] [p] JOIN [Orders] [o] ON [p].[ProductId] = [o].[LinkProductId] WHERE [p].[ProductCode] = 'ABC'
```

But also I could do:

```
DECLARE @ProductId INT;
SELECT @ProductId = [ProductId] FROM [Products] WHERE [ProductCode] = 'ABC'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Orders] WHERE [LinkProductId] = @ProductId
```

Would the first method be (mostly) the same as the second method, or in the first query would SQL first join each row in the two tables together, then search down looking for 'ABC' rather than looking up the PK for 'ABC' and just counting up the orders?

Also, is there a way to tell from the execution plan? I'm asking mostly about SQL-Server but it would be interesting if it was different for different engines.

Comment: The queries aren't the same unless you have a unique index on ProductCode. In general knowing `@ProductId` in advance might help if different ProductId have different selectivities and would get different plans but you won't see this without OPTION (RECOMPILE) anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, of course, edited question to include unique and not null. So they will make the same plan in most normal situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're basically identical. I've run the following on the AdventureWorks database:

```
DECLARE @ProductNumber NVARCHAR(50) = 'CA-7457';

SELECT 
    [Count] = COUNT(*)
FROM 
    [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail] [pod]
    JOIN [Production].[Product] [p] ON [pod].[ProductID] = [p].[ProductID]
WHERE
    [p].[ProductNumber] = @ProductNumber;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @ProductId INT;

SELECT
    @ProductId = [ProductID]
FROM 
    [Production].[Product]
WHERE
    [ProductNumber] = @ProductNumber;

SELECT 
    [Count] = COUNT(*)
FROM 
    [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail]
WHERE
    [ProductID] = @ProductId;
```

After including the execution plans the top one is 51% and the bottom two are both 25%, so there's nothing or close to nothing in it.

The only difference is the bottom two don't do the join, which accounts for 2% of the top query, and since it's CPU cost only and no IO, it makes little to no difference. They both use the same indexes and have the same number of rows returned at each stage.